# Mysqli - PHP to collect data from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to collect information from a HTML form then transfer the data to my sql database. I'm use Zampp phpmyadmin.

When I click submit, the data entered goes away but the success pop up does not pop up. There is no error. It just doesn't get sent to the database. Directly after the third IF statement is the ELSE statement that is not working - transferring the data to the database - this is in the second code file. I have no idea why.

This code is the index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 
include("functions/functions.php");

?>

<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" media="all"/>
    </head>


    <body>

    <div class = "container">

        <div id="head_wrap">
            <div id="header">
            <!-- logo goes here -->
                <img src="images/logo.png"/ style="float:left"/>
                <form method="post" action="" id="form1">
                    <strong>Email:</strong>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"/>
                    <strong>Password:</strong>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="*****" required="required"/>
                    <!-- the submit can be a button -->
                        <button name="login">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- this is where the second form and picture comes in on 
            main page -->
        <div id="content">
        <!-- second picture-->
            <div>
            <img src="images/image.png" style="float:left; margin-left:-40px;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="form2">
                <form action="" method="post">
                <h2>Sign Up Here</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Enter your 
                            name" required="required"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Password:</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="u_pass" placeholder="Enter your 
                            password" required="required"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Email:</td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="u_email" placeholder="Enter your 
                            email" required="required"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <!-- this is where they will pick their state -->
                        <td align="right">Country:</td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="u_country"required="required">
                            <option>Select a country</option>
                            <option>USA</option>
                            <option>Afghanistan</option>
                            <option>India</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td align="right" required="required">Gender:</td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="u_gender">
                            <option>Select a Gender</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Other</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" required="required">Birthday:</td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="u_birthday"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="6">
                        <button name="sign_up">Sign up</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                </form>
                <?php InsertUser();?>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- this is where the second form and picture ends on 
            main page -->



</body>
</html>
```

This code is the functions.php that is transferring the info to the database.

```
<?php

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","social_network") 
 or die("Connection was not established");

 function InsertUser(){
global $con;

if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])){
    $name = $_POST['u_name'];
    $pass = $_POST['u_pass'];
    $email = $_POST['u_email'];
    $country = $_POST['u_country'];
    $gender = $_POST['u_gender'];
    $b_day = $_POST['u_birthday'];
    $date = date("d-m-y");
    $status = "unverified";
    $posts = "No";

    $get_email = "select * from users where user_email='$email'";
    $run_email = mysqli_query($con,$get_email);
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_email);

    if($check==1){
        echo "<script>alert('Email has already been registered. Please try another one.')</script>";
        exit();     
    }
    if(strlen($pass)<8){
    echo "<script>alert('Password should be minimum 8 characters.')</script>";
        exit(); 
    }
    //this does not work. need to figure out why

    else {
        $insert = "INSERT into users (user_name,user_pass,user_email,user_country,user_gender,user_b_day,user_image,register_date,last_login,status,posts) values ('$name','$pass','$email','$country','$gender','$b_day','default.jpg','$date','$date','$status','$posts')";
        $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

            if($run_insert){
                echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!')</script>";
            }

    }


}



 }

 ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I just started learning this so everything is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli_error to get a meaningful error message:

```
if($run_insert)
{
  echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!')</script>";
}
else
{
  echo sprintf("Error %s executing %s", mysqli_error($con), $insert);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for that. There was an error in your code but after I fixed your code I found my error! Error %s executing %s Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'. Now I just have to figure out how to fix that lol